# Upload Images from file input to wordpress gallery

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, plugins

Im trying to upload images from afile input whose name and id is "images", to the wordpress gallery, so then i can use them in my plugin development,but im strugglig with it.

```
if (isset($_FILES['images'])) {
    $files = $_FILES['images'];

    foreach ($files['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $filename = $tmp_name;
        $parent_post_id = $post_id;
        $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            // Path to the uploaded file
            $file_path = $wp_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($filename);

            // Attachment data
            $attachment = array(
                'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
                'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );

            // Insert the attachment
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path, $parent_post_id);

            // Generate and update attachment metadata

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file_path);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);


            // Set the uploaded image as the featured image of the post
            set_post_thumbnail($parent_post_id, $attach_id);
       
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of code from the internet but nothing helped me, the code i used is based on this chapter of the wordpress documenttion:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/#user-contributed-notes

Any help? Thanks!!